# Google analytic lost account

Tags: google-analytics

I have taken over a .net site.

when I view the source I see it has the Google analytic code.

```
ga('create', 'UA-51570230-1'...
```

But to access this you need to login to your gmail account, but am not sure what it is.

is there any other way to get the Google analytic information?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get access to the Google Analytics account is to have the owner of the account 'UA-51570230-1' give you access.   There is also no way to find out who or what email address owns the account 'UA-51570230-1'.

Unfortunately the only thing you can do really is to either track down the owner of the account or start over creating a new account and changing the code on the site.